# Add "PowerShell Here" and "Command Window Here" to right click menu for drives, folders, and current directories

Tags: powershell, context-menu, right-click

I've tried applying and editing the .reg files, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992486/open-powershell-here-in-background-directory) and [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-command-prompt-here-always-display-for-folders-in-windows-vista/)

But can't seem to get a "PowerShell Here" and "Command Window" here option in all right click menus without holding Shift for some.

Is there a way to add these to every right click menu (i.e., a drives, folders, and white space within a folder) with a single .reg file?

This question is different form [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/579632/can-i-add-a-windows-explorer-context-menu-option-to-start-command-prompt-in-the)

in that I am also including right clicking in the white space of a currently opened folder (not just clicking directly on a folder or drive).

Comment: Yes there is. There must be. I remember having something set this up for me in Windows 95, and I wish it was easier to set these up yourself nowadays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add a Windows Explorer context menu option to start command prompt in the selected directory?](http://superuser.com/questions/579632/can-i-add-a-windows-explorer-context-menu-option-to-start-command-prompt-in-the) See my answer there. The *Extended* verb should not be present in any of the 3 locations, i.e. Drive, Directory and Directory\Background.

Comment: "This question is different form this one" - No it isn't. Read my answer there carefully. Your use case *is* handled as well (I also mentioned it explicitly in my comment above). You mentioned 3 context menus; I mentioned 3 registry keys. Is this so hard to correlate?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  I overlooked the third one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that string value "extended" is either renamed or removed to turn of 'shift' requirement,

As for the other thing, add a string value named "NoWorkingDirectory"
This will allow both to appear even when no folder was clicked upon,

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for PowerShell:

> 1. “Win + R”, run regedit to open Registry Editor.
> 2. Go to the locations respectively:
>
>    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell
>       HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell
>       HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Powershell
>
> For each key, right click the key on the left panel, “Permissions…”,
>   “Advanced”, change the owner to “Admistrators”, then assign “Full
>   Control” - “Allow” to “Admistrators”. Press “OK”.
>
> 3. For each key, delete the “Extended” key on the right panel.

[source](https://www.fyears.org/2017/04/open-powershell-window-here.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
```

; Add_enhanced_cmd_and_powershell_to_menu.reg
; This adds Command and Powershell sub menu options

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\01MenuCmd]
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open]
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt Elevated"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open]
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\01MenuCmd]
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"

Answer (score 0):

I created a fully automated solution to add PS and CMD context items.
Just run set_registry.cmd and it will update registry to add two buttons when click RMB on folder or inside some opened folder:

This will change owner of registry keys to admin and add context menus
[Change registry to enable PS and CWD context menus](https://github.com/beliaev-maksim/cmd_ps_windows_registry)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Mokubai, I see your point, unfortunately it is too tricky and you cannot take only parts of the code. I explained in two sentences what is does and how. But technical implementation should be checked in the source