# How do I set right-click on folder background to show "Open PowerShell Window here"?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, context-menu

I know that you can get this option when you Shift+right-click, but I don't want to hold down Shift to see this option.

For instance, when Git installs on Windows, I don't have to Shift+right-click to see the "Open Git bash here", as it shows up just on right clicks as well.

Checking registry, I see that under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command` the default value `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" "--cd=%1"`

Under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command` the default value is: `powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'`.

So I figure that if I set the default entry under a custom location `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowershellHere\command` to be `powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%1'`, I would see the PowerShell option in the right-click menu, but it didn't work :(

What can I do?

Comment: Have you rebooted? Sometimes these changes only start working after explorer is reloaded.

Comment: [Add "PowerShell Here" and "Command Window Here" to right click menu for drives, folders, and current directories](//superuser.com/q/918401) and see the comments under the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill I [followed the answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/579632/can-i-add-a-windows-explorer-context-menu-option-to-start-command-prompt-in-the), but still don't see a menu option under right click alone...

Comment: @LPChip Yep, I restarted explorer.exe too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create a new registry key here:**

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowershellHere`

(for the `(Default)` value you can leave it blank or add &PowershellHere and you could use right-click then the letter p as a hot key.)

**Create another registry key here:**
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowershellHere\command`

Give the `(Default)`  string the value of:

`powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'`

or

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'`

**Alternately, you can hijack the existing key at:** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell`
by deleting the `Extended` and `NoWorkingDirectory` subkeys (however you will need to start `regedit` with administrative privileges.

Comment: This is exactly the file I used. PowerShell still doesn't show up in the menu options.

Comment: Just remove the information that doesn’t apply and delete the comments

Comment: This seems to work at least in terms of showing up the `PowerShellHere` option upon right click. When I actually tried to click on the menu option, it gave me an error saying that it doesn't have a command associated with it, but I think that was because it wants a sub-key named `cmd` and not `command` as you have in your answer. But I think there's a better way of doing this based on this answer: https://superuser.com/a/579691/298477

Comment: I'll update your answer, for you to see what I mean! Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Okay, updated your answer. See what you think of it. Basically, I think the values `Extended` and `NoWorkingDirectory` are under a different location than in Windows Vista, which the old answer was based on. The principle still applies (in terms of removing them). Also, I think you have to do some permission stuff?

Comment: nice, I didn't want to break my context menu so I didn't try mucking with the existing powershell settings.  thanks for the extra information! I haven't needed to change any permissions, but I'm using an admin account.

Comment: sippybear, me too! I'm on an admin account. Maybe I have to start regedit in admin mode?

Comment: @user89 definitely worth a try! it's giving you grief specifically when you try to modify the Powershell keys and not the PowershellHere keys, right?

Comment: sippybear, yup. okay, so when i started regedit in admin mode, i didn't need to set permissions either. i updated the answer based on this

Comment: Nice, but I suggest changing the command to `powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath \"%V\"` so that it doesn't break with folder names with embedded `'` chars.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reg file I use to add Powershell commands to the Background menu in Windows 10;

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Add_Open_Powershell_to_Context_Menu.reg

;Right-Click Background only

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\Background\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\Background\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"
```

Comment: The first two `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
` sections are duplicated...

Comment: This is good. It creates a right-click sub-menu with an option for a regular console, and an elevated console. But it doesn't work on clicking folders themselves (only the background when in a folder in Explorer).

Answer (score 1):

### Run this in Powershell to add Context Menus

This approach yields a right-click context menu that works both on folders, and in the background of folders to achieve a menu looking like this:

[image: Powershell Context menu]

1. Run an Administrative Powershell prompt
2. Paste the following commands:

---

```
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /f
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /f
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open" /f
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas" /f


######## Add “Powershell Console Here” options to context menu

#### Right-Click Folder context menu

reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /v MUIVerb /t REG_SZ /d "Powershell" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /v Icon /t REG_SZ /d "powershell.exe" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /v ExtendedSubCommandsKey /t REG_SZ /d "Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell" /f

#### Right-Click Background context menu

reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /v MUIVerb /t REG_SZ /d "Powershell" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /v Icon /t REG_SZ /d "powershell.exe" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowershellConsoleHere" /v ExtendedSubCommandsKey /t REG_SZ /d "Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell" /f

### Create sub-context menu options
##  Sub-context menu option: Console
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open" /v MUIVerb /t REG_SZ /d "Console" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open" /v Icon /t REG_SZ /d "powershell.exe" /f

# Set default key value "(Default)"
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command" /f /ve /d "powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

##  Sub-context menu option: Elevated Console
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas" /v MUIVerb /t REG_SZ /d "Elevated Console" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas" /v Icon /t REG_SZ /d "powershell.exe" /f
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas" /v HasLUAShield /t REG_SZ /d "" /f

# Set default key value "(Default)"
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command" /f /ve /d "powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"
```

---

This is based on the MSDN blog article [Enhancing the “Open Command Prompt here” Context Menu experience](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrew_richards/2017/03/01/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome library

https://github.com/kerol2r20/Windows-terminal-context-menu