# "wrong path" after running command via address bar in explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

after I run a command via the address bar in an explorer window, the path shown in the address bar will point to the command and not to the current folder

is there any known fix how to prevent this?

**steps to reproduce:**

1. open explorer
2. place cursor into address bar
3. run command (e.g cmd)
4. place cursor into adress bar -> path will point to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Comment: Explorer is not meant to be a working environment. You should be looking into the Command Prompt, or perhaps the Start menu Run command (Winkey+R).

Comment: This is bugging me also a lot and was hoping to find an answer here. Too bad that there isn’t really an answer to your question. Oh btw, my quickfix is then to press `Alt+Arrow Up` and then `Enter` to go one folder up and then again into the same folder and have the correct path in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

When any command is entered in the adress bar of the explorer the command is executed in the CMD in the default work directory of user's files.

So instead of typing the command in address bar, right click  while holding the shift and select "open poweshell window here" to open a poweshell in the opened directory and run the command there